# Random system Freezes on two different machines in the same room

Tags: arch-linux, hardware, freeze

I have been encountering a problem with 2 desktop workstations in my home office. This problem began on an old dell machine, and when I finally gave up diagnosing it, I purchased a new desktop, only to have the problem follow. (Machine specs below).

The problem is that both machines will simply stop responding. No mouse or keyboard input, can't switch to another tty, nothing. The only way to get the machine back is to power cycle. When I bring it back there are no errors in xorg logs, nor in the systemd journal, the logging simply stops at the point of the freeze. This can happen when idle, or under load. It happens between 2 and 12 hours after the machine is booted.The machine is also not reachable via ssh.
   I don't have detailed specs on the old machine, it was a freebie I picked up from someone. It was a core2duo with 2GB of RAM running Fedora 21
  The new machine is a 4th gen i5, 32GB of RAM, Nvidia Geforce GT 720 using the nouveau driver. When I first got it I installed Fedora 21, when I thought the OS may be the issue I installed Arch.

My troubleshooting steps thus far:

- I have replaced the computer
- Changed Distros from Fedora to Arch
- I thought this may be a power related issue, like a drop in the outlet voltage so I tried different outlets in the same room, and eventually put the machine on a new UPS to try and eliminate the house power and the power strip as an issue
- I  just switched out the mouse, if it happens again the keyboard is next.

At this point the only things that are the same are the location, the modem and router, the monitor and the network cable.

Comment: Which kernel(s) are you running? Have you tried LTS?

Comment: 3.17.6-1-ARCH I have not tried any LTS Distros

Comment: Do you have headphones that have any metal on them? I had a similar problem that used to occur only during the winter. It turned out that static charge from touching the metal on my headphones was causing it.

Comment: I do, but they have not been plugged in every time its happened. Good thought though.

Comment: Update:  I've booted the machine into a non graphical mode, and unplugged all peripherals. I'm going to see how it does this way to see if it may related to Xorg, the video drivers, or a peripheral.

Comment: Arch has an LTS kernel: you can install it alongside the vanilla one and choose which to boot into; might be worth a shot...

Comment: I was unaware of that, I may give that a try too. Thanks!

Comment: Update:  Issue occurred again in multi user mode. I have switched locations in my house and am testing further.

Comment: So, happened in a different room ( that is on a different circuit in the house) I have moved it back to its original location, installed the nvidia drivers and blacklisted nouveau. An interesting note with that is that there was a strange pink vertical line about 2 or 3 pixels wide on the monitor before. It is gone now, hopefully that is a good sign

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem was with the **nouveau** drivers. I installed the Nvidia drivers from Arch's core repo and the issue has not occured again in over 24 hours. Thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: Strange. My experience has been exactly the other way around: nouveau rock solid (after a rocky start), nVidia leading to all sorts of "interesting" behaviour. But the nVidia experiments I gave up a *long* way back, now using bog-standard Fedora.